# Why won't my Fujifilm X-E3 focus or take photos?

Tags: autofocus, troubleshooting, fujifilm

I’m new to photography but I bought an X-E3 today, pressed some buttons, and I’m not sure what happened but my camera won’t focus now. In the photo, it’s on auto and I’ve tried changing the settings, but the camera seems to be unfocused no matter what? And when I press the shutter button, nothing happens.

I’m at a loss! Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Notice that the aperture is listed as "F 0". I bet the lens isn't attached right — try removing it and putting it back.

Comment: That seems a very likely answer. Some lenses I've seen (maybe not for your camera line) have a switch on the lens, too, that needs to be in "auto" mode for AF to occur. Otherwise the manual focusing ring is disengaged (or vice-versa, the AF motors are disabled) to prevent you fighting the lens and damaging it.

Comment: Also, by default Fujifilm bodies are set to "do not take picture without lens attached". That's why you cannot take pictures. Consider setting that option ON if you are using a manual focus lens on your X-E3.